why is my loop only sometimes working correctly when the code is nearly identical?
Here is part of my python code, it's mostly working how I want, except for when the guessed letter is wrong, it loops incorrectly. I want it to loop back to asking for a letter, but it's looping back to asking for a word. If the letter guessed is correct, it loops as intended. How do I fix this?
# start of game
letterTrue = input("Do you want to play?")

# variables
triesLeft = 1
guessList = []
triesRemaining = 3

# start guessing
while letterTrue == "yes" and triesLeft == True :
    word = input("\nEnter a word to start the game.")
    wordList = list(word)

# letter1 input
    letter1 = input("\nEnter a letter.") 

# letter 1 correct
    if letter1 in wordList :
        print("The letter", (letter1), "is in the word.")
        triesRemaining -= triesLeft
        print (triesRemaining, "tries left.")
        guessList.append(letter1)

# letter 1 wrong
    elif letter1 not in wordList :
        letterTrue == False
        (print("The letter", (letter1), "is not in the word."))
        triesRemaining -= triesLeft
        print (triesRemaining, "tries left.")



The prompt for word shouldn't be in the loop if you don't want to repeat it. Isn't that obvious?

...when the code is nearly identical? - to what?

You need to be consistent about whether variables are boolean, string, or numeric. triesLeft is a number, you sshouldn't compare with True.

The loop shouldn't run at all. triesLeft is initially set to 1 and you check triesLeft == True, which should evaluate to False.

@ndc85430 Booleans are a subtype of integers in Python, so 1 == True is true.

But you never change triesLeft during the loop. You probably should be checking triesRemaining, which is decremented.

There are so many problems with your code I think you need to start fresh, and think carefully about each step. We can rewrite it, but you won't learn anything if someone else does your homework for you.

letterTrue == False is a comparison, not an assignment. It doesn't do anything useful as a statement. But changing it to an assignment will cause the loop to end after the first missed guess.

When your elif condition is the exact opposite of the if condition you should just use else:

I belive this does what you are trying to do. I moved the wordlist initialization out of the loop, so you don't reset the word with every letter guess. I also moved some of the duplicate code out of the if/else blocks.
# start of game
letterTrue = input("Do you want to play?")

# variables
triesLeft = 1
guessList = []
triesRemaining = 3

word = input("\nEnter a word to start the game.")
wordList = list(word)

# start guessing
while letterTrue == "yes" and triesLeft == True :

# letter1 input
    letter1 = input("\nEnter a letter.") 

# letter 1 correct
    if letter1 in wordList :
        print("The letter", (letter1), "is in the word.")
        guessList.append(letter1)

# letter 1 wrong
    elif letter1 not in wordList :
        letterTrue == False
        (print("The letter", (letter1), "is not in the word."))
        
    triesRemaining -= triesLeft
    print (triesRemaining, "tries left.")


Don't just post code. Explain what they did wrong and how you fixed it.

There are many problems with their code. You fixed one of them, but not the rest.

I appreciate the comments. I edited my answer. What other issues did you see with the code?

See my comments below the question.
